# Can I use Spring.NET to inject dependencies in a created instance?

Tags: c#, spring.net

Is it possible to to something like this using Spring.NET IoC container?

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
ContextRegistry.GetContext().InjectDepenencies(instance);
// instance has the defined dependencies set
```

This would come in handy. Of couse I could use `ContextRegistry.GetContext().Get("name")` but that would create a new instance of the defined object. I would need to set the dependencies of an already created object.

Comment: I know it is possible in Unity, don't know about Spring.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three options available, the first one matches what you want.

- IApplicationContext.ConfigureObject(object target, string name)

  This configures the target object using the object definition which is matched by the name argument.
- IApplicationContext.Get(string name,
  object[] arguments)

  Which will either use the constructor
  or a static factory method which will
  receive the arguments as specified.
- GenericApplicationContext.RegisterObjectDefinition(string name, IObjectDefinition definition)

  You can use it to register dependencies at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`ContextRegistry.GetContext().Get("name")` will not create a new instance if `name` is defined as [singleton](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0-RC1/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-scopes-singleton) which is the default scope in spring.net.

Comment: Thats true, but singleton behaviour is not an option in this case.

Comment: If you use Spring to create the object instead of doing it manually it will already have the dependencies injected. So could you elaborate a little more on your scenario?

Comment: I would use this e. g. when the object was not created in any of my code but outside of the scope of my app, like in a third party framework.